# Concatenate value of 2 columns in datagridview (winform)

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview that contains bound and unbound column and i want to combine the value of 2 desired bound column (a and b) so the column c (which is unbound) is contained value from a and b

Is it possible?

Nb : sorry i cant post photos for better explanation

Thanks

Comment: It's possible in different ways. The easiest ,probably, is using `DataTable` having 3 columns, a, b and c, which c is an expression column having a+b as expression.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in different ways. The easiest, probably would be using `DataTable` having 3 columns, a, b and c, which c is an [expression column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataColumn_Expression) having a+b as expression.

Another option, is using [`RowPrePaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint?view=netframework-4.7.2) event of `DataGridView`. (You can also use some other events like `CellFormatting`.)

**Example - Expression Column**

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string), "CONVERT(A, System.String) + B");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "One");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Two");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

**Example - RowPrePaint**

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("A", "A");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("B", "B");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("C", "C");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, "One");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2, "Two");
dataGridView1.RowPrePaint += (s, a) =>
{
    if (a.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var g = (DataGridView)s;
        g["C", a.RowIndex].Value = $"{g["A", a.RowIndex].Value}{g["B", a.RowIndex].Value}";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can generate value for "c" column cells on demand in `CellFormatting` event:

```
private void Grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;

    int cIndex = 2;
    if (e.ColumnIndex != cIndex) return;

    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    int aIndex = 0, bIndex = 1, row = e.RowIndex;

    e.Value = String.Format("{0} {1}", grid[aIndex, row].Value, grid[bIndex, row].Value);
    e.FormattingApplied = true;
}
```

Comment: The reason that I mentioned the `CellFormatting` as well as `RowPrePaint` but preferred to post an example about `RowPrePaint`, is because if you update the value of the first two columns, the third column will not be immediately updated because the third column is not in the clip bound, while `RowPrePaint` will always raise. If you want to use `CellFormatting` for an editable `DataGridView`, you need to invalidate the formatted cell: `grid.InvalidateCell(grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]);`.